# Using the Elasticsearch test framework in IntelliJ, how to resolve the jar hell regarding idea_rt.jar?

Tags: elasticsearch, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am trying to use the provided Elasticsearch java test framework to do some integration testing on my es project.
I have a very simple test setup in IntelliJ:

```
class FormTest : ESIntegTestCase() {

    override fun nodeSettings(nodeOrdinal: Int): Settings = Settings.builder()
        .put(super.nodeSettings(nodeOrdinal))
        //.put("node.mode", "network")
        .build()

    @org.junit.Test fun start() {
        ensureGreen()
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: found jar hell in test classpath

    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase.<clinit>(ESTestCase.java:190)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$2.run(RandomizedRunner.java:592)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
duplicate jar [C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\181.5281.24\lib\idea_rt.jar] on classpath: ...
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.parseClassPath(JarHell.java:142)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.parseClassPath(JarHell.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapForTesting.<clinit>(BootstrapForTesting.java:90)
    ... 4 more
```

I found some ways to bypass the jar hell check, but how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem when I stumbled across: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#configuring-ides-and-running-tests

In particular, I had to set `idea.no.launcher=true` and restart my IntelliJ.

> In order to run tests directly from IDEA 2017.2 and above, it is required to disable the IDEA run launcher in order to avoid idea_rt.jar causing "jar hell". This can be achieved by adding the -Didea.no.launcher=true JVM option. Alternatively, idea.no.launcher=true can be set in the idea.properties

Also, you may need to:

> For IDEA 2017.3 and above, in addition to the JVM option, you will need to go to Run->Edit Configurations->...->Defaults->JUnit and verify that the Shorten command line setting is set to user-local default: none. You may also need to remove ant-javafx.jar from your classpath if that is reported as a source of jar hell.

Finally, make sure you have asserts on:

> The Elasticsearch codebase makes heavy use of Java asserts and the test runner requires that assertions be enabled within the JVM. This can be accomplished by passing the flag -ea to the JVM on startup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I cannot verify this at the moment, but will accept it for now.

Answer (score 2):

Since I was surprised by how long my classpath was, I tried to use the `shorten command line` option, which worked.

Edit your run configuration and set the `Shorten command line` field to `JAR manifest`.